# Problem including my email address on Careers

Tags: support, status-completed, jobs, openid

I only use one openID for all of the stack exchange sites, which is my Google login.  I just tried to update my full name on my Careers profile, and received this error:

> You cannot use openid for the primary and alt credentials.

I'm guessing that this is because the email address field contains the same gmail address used for my openID, but I have not edited my email address, it was pre-filled (presumably either from when I requested the invite or imported from my SO profile).  I only tried to change my full name.

And so I have a couple of questions:

1. Since I have no intention of publishing a different email address, do I need to create a new openID to log into careers with?
2. I do not have a full careers profile, having only requested an invite today.  Will this conflict affect my chances of getting an invite or is it pending? (note, I'm not trying to hurry anyone along, just want to make sure I'm in the queue for assessment and the request didn't fail silently)

Comment: I see that my name has now been magically inserted into my profile, thank you mysterious benefactor :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This issue has been fixed and will go out with the next push later today.

Sincerely,
mysterious benefactor

Comment: Awesome, thanks Nick.  Are you able to confirm whether I'm in the assessment queue for an invite, or if I need to resubmit?

Comment: @shanethehat: no problem.  It looks like someone cleared out the queue this morning, you should have an invite waiting.